# Are any of the "community members" SE Inc. is talking to ... around here?

Tags: discussion, community, feedback, podcast, the-loop

The latest [podcast](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/21/podcast-a-chat-with-our-ceo-about-the-future-of-our-company-and-community) mentions again that there are "community members" that get to *talk* to SE Inc., for example via streaming during the SE Inc. "come together" in Austin lately. Also the "post loop" [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/11/the-loop-1-how-we-conduct-research-on-the-community-team/) mentions that part about "user research".

I am simply wondering: is *anyone* amongst us who is in that group of people SE Inc. is talking with? Or at least: do you know someone who is?

Comment: Have you looked at [George Stocker's prediction](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1218161698105892864) on what's coming for SO in 2020? If not, I suggest you do. Based on this, I would predict that people hanging out on Meta.SE are not the [main] target of this initiative, so I would be [pleasantly] surprised if any of us had been approached. Or at least non-mod people. I might be totally wrong though, I'll admit that.

Comment: @Laf-ReinstateMonica I wrote an answer linking to that twitter thread ... yesterday already. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342545/285661 ... so yes, I have seen it. And I agree, I consider it *unlikely* that people were just waiting to be asked such a question to speak up. Nonetheless, I think that a few "top contributors" might also read/write here, thus I see a certain chance that we have people amongst us who were contacted by SE Inc.

Comment: I caught this thread from Shog's twitter, totally missed your answer (just threw an upvote at you for it ;) ). Sorry for pointing you to it, hopefully it will be useful for other readers. Your question is still a good question though, I'm curious to see if anyone in here was contacted.

Comment: @Laf-ReinstateMonica You are very welcome. And some links can't be made public often enough anyway. And I am not talking about the ones to my own content ;-)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339750/282094

Answer (score 49):

To answer the question directly (at least I *think* I can do this to an extent):

- I have been contacted by Stack Exchange, and have had high level talks with two of the highest ranking officials at Stack Exchange, for a total of 90 minutes, between October and November 2019.
- Both talks have been via telepresence, with webcams on in a professional manner that I'm accustomed to when working via telepresence.
- I delivered and expressed my opinions on the matters facing the exchange sites at the time.
- New circumstances arising recently have led me to pause interactions.

**I will not be answering or commentating any further** on my personal interactions out of respect for the two one-on-one's I've had.

Comment: Thank you. A precise statement, more than I hoped for.

Comment: This is great, thanks for sharing. If I may ask just one question: how was the dialogue initiated? For example, were you sent a "You have been randomly selected..." type email, or was it something more hand-picked?

Comment: Was this something you applied for? Did it happen "by hand" via mutual social networks? Is an audience with the company now an automatic perk that comes at a specific reputation level?

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8:  It felt like it was more hand-picked more than anything else, honestly.  I can't really describe any heuristic or any motivations other than that.

Comment: @RobertColumbia:  I never applied for it or made any overt indication that I was *seeking* communication in this fashion.  Don't know if it comes at a rep level or not.  *Maybe* it's due to how active I've been on Meta over the last six months?  Dunno.